# Activity switching not working android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

I am working on an android app that has two activities. One is the menu screen and the other is the one that the user actually uses once they have made a selection. The second activity does all of its processing in a worker thread. When I make the selection to move on to the second activity, it "flashes" the activity for about 100ms. I found some logs that look like they would tell me what I need to fix if I knew what they meant.

```
02-29 10:52:33.850: I/ActivityManager(1255): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.wcf.imageShare/.ImageShareActivity }
02-29 10:52:33.920: W/InputManagerService(1255): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@45c0a198 (uid=10097 pid=24918)
02-29 10:52:33.936: W/WindowManager(1255): No window to dispatch pointer action
02-29 10:52:33.952: I/ActivityManager(1255): Displayed activity com.wcf.imageShare/.ImageShareActivity: 96 ms (total 96 ms)
02-29 10:52:34.000: W/WindowManager(1255): No window to dispatch pointer action 1
```

The program itself is not crashing, it just takes me back to the menuview and displays my choices again. Here is the code I am using to switch activities

```
lstServers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public  void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Beacon.activeServer = position;
            Intent uploadIntent = new Intent(inst,ImageShareActivity.class);
            inst.startActivity(uploadIntent);
        }
    });
```

inst holds the 'this' variable of the activity that the code is running in since I couldn't reference it by using 'this'

Here is the onCreate of the activity I am trying to switch to:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    try
    {
        progBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prog_txt);
        btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cancel);
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0) 
            {
                try {
                    uploaderThread.interrupt();
                    Uploader.CancelUpload();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        uploaderThread.start();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Uploader ERROR",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And finally the part of the manifest file that has to do with the two activities.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity
        android:name=".ImageShareActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ServerChoiceActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or know of something that I am missing?

Thanks

Nick Long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to this :

```
lstServers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public  void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Beacon.activeServer = position;
            Intent uploadIntent = new Intent(your_current_activty.this,ImageShareActivity.class);
            uploadIntent.startActivity();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please explain why -1.Who is his guy ?

Comment: That won't work. When I try that it won't compile. In this case, the 'this' variable refers to my OnItemClickListener so the declaration of the uploadIntent won't compile. Then when I changed the inst.startActivity(uploadIntent) to uploadIntent.startActivity() it says that the method is not defined.

Comment: @nick I modify my answer.please try that.Give your activity name in place of your_current_activity

Comment: I found out the reason I was unable to display the activity for more than about 0.1 seconds was that I haden't set an action or the extras for my activity. I needed to use the uploadIntent.setActivity() method and I also copied the extras from the current intent into the new intent.